# One XElement from multiple streams

Tags: c#, stream, xelement

I need to create method which will concatenate multiple Xelements into one.
I created below method:

```
        static void DoStuff(string IP, string login, string password, string port)
        {
            CommonMethods cm = new CommonMethods();            
            WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
            XElement output = null;

            try
            {
                webClient = cm.ConnectCiscoUnityServerWebClient(IP, login, password);
                int rowsPerPage = 100;
                int pageNumber = 1;
                Console.WriteLine("Getting logins from " + IP);

                do
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Downloading " + pageNumber + " page");
                    string uri = @"https://" + IP + ":" + port + "/vmrest/users?bla&rowsPerPage=" + rowsPerPage + "&pageNumber=" + pageNumber;
                    Stream stream = webClient.OpenRead(uri);
                    output = XElement.Load(stream);                    
                    pageNumber++;
                }
                while (output.HasElements);

                Console.WriteLine(output);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                cm.LogErrors(ex.ToString(), System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name.ToString());
            }
        }
```

but in Do While loop the output is overwritten. Could you please provide me some solution which will concatenate the output into one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overriding values of `output` element on each iteration. Instead create resulting element and add new elements to it on each iteration:

```
CommonMethods cm = new CommonMethods();            
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
XElement output = null;

try
{
    webClient = cm.ConnectCiscoUnityServerWebClient(IP, login, password);
    int rowsPerPage = 100;
    int pageNumber = 1;
    Console.WriteLine("Getting logins from " + IP);
    XElement result = new XElement("result"); // will hold results

    do
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Downloading " + pageNumber + " page");
        string uri = @"https://" + IP + ":" + port + 
           "/vmrest/users?bla&rowsPerPage=" + 
           rowsPerPage + "&pageNumber=" + pageNumber;

        Stream stream = webClient.OpenRead(uri);
        output = XElement.Load(stream);
        result.Add(output); // add current output to results
        pageNumber++;
    }
    while (output.HasElements);

    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    cm.LogErrors(ex.ToString(), MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name.ToString());
}
```

Resulting element can be first of loaded `output` elements. Then you can do some queries to next elements and add results to resulting element. It's hard to tell more without seeing data you are working with.